# PHP 'IN' query returns only 1 row

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Can anyone explain me why the last query returns always 1 row. it should return more than 1 because there're a lot of records in the database!

Sorry for my bad english

```
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT book_id FROM ".DB_PREF."books_cats_list WHERE cat_id='".$cat."'");
            if($row=mysql_num_rows($query))
            {

                //fetching all books from $cat category
                for($i=0; $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $i++)
                {
                    $records[$i]=$fetch['book_id'];
                }

                //Joining all records in a string for next query
                $records=implode(",",$records);

                //returning num rows if there're book_id records in $records array
                $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREF."books WHERE book_id IN ('".$records."')");
                $rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
                echo $rows;
```

Comment: You should use mysql_fetch_assoc() to read the second query results, just like on the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is going to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id IN ('2,3,4,5')
```

Note how inside the `IN`, it's all one string.  This one string will be converted to an int.  This happens by stopping at the 1st non-number character.  So, the query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id IN (2)
```

Try to remove the single quotes inside the `IN`.

NOTE: If your values aren't ints, try changing the the `implode` to: `implode("','",$records)`, and keep the quotes inside the `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance I suggest the for loop:

```
for($i=0; $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); $i++)
```

Should be a while loop:

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

I expect it is only doing one record with that for loop code.

I suggest however you do a left join select

```
SELECT * FROM books_cats_list as cat
left join books as book on cat.book_id = book.book_id
WHERE cat.cat_id='$cat'
```

This will be far more optimal in terms of database performance I expect.